# How to define font-size different divs

Tags: html, css, fonts

In my project, I have three divs.

"upBtDiv and ulfDiv" are in attFile div.

The font-size in upBtDiv is 16px, and it works successfully.But the font-size of 10px in ulfDiv works fail.The font-size in ulfDiv is remain 16px.

When i define .attFile{margin-left:15%;margin-top:5%;font-szie:10px}, and it works fine.But the font-size of "upBtDiv and ulfDiv" are both 10px.

Here is my css code:

```css
.attFile {
    margin-left:15%; 
    margin-top:5%
}
.upBtDiv { 
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block; 
   display:inline;font-size:16px
}
.upBtDiv label { cursor:pointer }
.upBtDiv input { 
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0;
    border:solid transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    cursor:pointer;
    width:66%
}
.ulfDiv { 
    height:10px;
    line-height:22px; 
    margin:10px 0;
    font-size:10px
} 
.ulfDiv .delimg,
.dwlimg {
    color:#090;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none
}
.ulfDiv:hover .delimg { 
    display: inline-block;
}
.ulfDiv:hover .dwlimg {
    display: inline-block;
}
.delimg:hover { color:blue; }
.dwlimg:hover { color:blue; }
```

```html
<div class="attFile" id="attFileId">
    <div class="upBtDiv">
        <label style="color:green">attfile:</label>
        <input type="file" id="fulId" name="mypic">
    </div>
    <div class="ulfDiv" id="ulfId1">
        <b class='dataname'>30k</b>
        <span class='delimg' rel='" + data.pic + "'>delete</span>
        <a class='dwlimg' href='files/" + data.pic + "' target='_blank'>add</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems nothing wrong in my code.I suppose the overflow:hidden attribute of upBtDiv is the reason.But i have no idea about it. Who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.attFile > .upBtDiv{
  font-size: 28px;
}
.attFile > .ulfDiv{
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="attFile" id="attFileId">
 <div class="upBtDiv" >
  <label style="color:green">attfile:</label>  <input type="file"   id="fulId" name="mypic">
 </div>
 <div class="ulfDiv" id="ulfId1">
  <b class='dataname' >30k</b> 
  <span class='delimg' rel='"+data.pic+"'>delete</span>
  <a class='dwlimg' href='files/"+data.pic+"'      target='_blank'>add</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ">" means what?